# How can I specify CODEPIPELINE as source type and artifacts for codebuild project in CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

I have below cloudformation template:

```
CodeBuildProject:
    Type: AWS::CodeBuild::Project
    Properties:
      Name: project
      ServiceRole: !Ref CodeBuildRole
      Artifacts:
        Type: CODEPIPELINE
      Source:
        Type: CODEPIPELINE
...
```

The `Artifiacts` and `Source -> Type` are `CODEPIPELINE`. I am translating above code to CDK but couldn't find the right API to specify these values.

I read this doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-codebuild.Source.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-codebuild.IArtifacts.html but it doesn't have any method to load source from CODEPIPELINE.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [PipelineProject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-codebuild.CommonProjectProps.html):

> A convenience class for CodeBuild Projects that are used in CodePipeline.

An example of how the class can be used is in:

- [Creating a pipeline using the AWS CDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/codepipeline_example.html)

Comment: Does this PipelineProject mean using `Type: CODEPIPELINE`?